# For/In Loop with a new object

Tags: javascript, key, for-in-loop

I've been working on a problem and am having a hard time figuring out what to do from here.

Here's what I must do:
Create an object called me. Give it a key of name with the value being your name, and another key of age with the value being your age. Then alert your name using dot notation.

I just started coding about a week or two ago.  I'm not good at this and I'm getting stressed looking around the internet and not finding a reasonably obvious way I can solve this.  I'm not sure if anything I have typed out is viable or if I'm just missing something small.

I am supposed to use a for/in loop.

Help would be amazing, thanks.

```
var me = new Object();
me.name = "Brody";
me.age = "18";

function showProps(obj, objName) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        result += objName + "." + i + " = " + obj[i] + "\n";
    }
  }
  return result;
}
alert();
```

Comment: You've called *alert* but not given it anything to show, see rfornal's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following javascript

```
var me = new Object();
me.name = "Brody";
me.age = "18";
alert(me.name);
```

Updated version

```
var me = {
    "name" : "Brody",
    "age" : "18"
};
for(var key in me) {
  if(key == "name")     
   alert(me[key]);

}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zda33kug/1/)

Comment: Well. I had that before on a previous submission.. I was told to redo said project and utilize a for/in loop, and I am unsure why it needs one and how I would do it.

Comment: @BrodyMacfarlane—perhaps this is an exercise, so you are being asked to use a for..in loop so you learn how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's either ...

```
alert(me.name);
```

... or using the `showProps()` function ...

```
alert(showProps(me, "me"));
```

... my thought would be the first one and `showProps()` is not needed.